# FOSOAuthServerBundle Create Client

Tags: rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I'm currently trying to setup FOSOAuthServerBundle with my Symfony2 app.
Everything seems to be setup and functional, anyway I'm stuck after the installation.
What is the proper workflow with URLs to get the access_token ?

I tried /oauth/v2/auth, but sounds like I need to define a Client object first.

How to create/generate Client ? Clients are always supposed to be created manually ?

FOSOAuthServerBundle doc is great, but seems to skip all the usage workflow. Am I supposed to check the OAuth2 doc for this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. You should be using the oAuth2 RFC to determine which workflow you want to use.  In regards to client registration the RFC specifically states that the means through which a client registers is beyond the scope of the specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2).

With that being said I can give you some insight into how I did this.  My application is a mobile phone application that connects to several services running on various servers.  I'm also using the `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant`.

The way I approached this was: when the application loads, the first thing it does is to check if it has an `oAuth2 client id`.  If it doesn't, then it POSTS to a create client endpoint I've setted up with the meta-data I need.  The endpoint validates the POST, creates the client and returns the client information.  The application stores the client id and the process doesn't have to be repeated the next time.

1. Application loads;
2. Application checks for oAuth2 client id;
3. If there is one, the process ends;
4. If there isn't, it posts to http://www.example.com/client;
5. If we get a 200, store the oAuth2 client id.

I could have also created the oAuth2 client when the user created an account in the application, but I wanted to make the registration process as fast as possible.  Creating the client would have added some extra waiting time to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html

It's quite simple to convert to Doctrine, whether you use it.

There's a command-line that does exactly what you need: create a Client!